# Diferença entre o método ".attr()" e ".data()"

Tags: jquery, html5, html5-data, jquery-data

Noto que existe uma diferença entre atualizar ou aplicar um atributo `data` utilizando o método de jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) e o método [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Os exemplos em baixo apresentados podem ser vistos [neste JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/K3sLR/).

- #### Aplicar valor a atributo não existente

  Se aplicar o valor através do método `.attr()` e depois alterar o mesmo através do método `.data()`, o resultado ao recolher o valor varia em conformidade com o método utilizado para aplicar o mesmo:

  ```html
  <div id="myBanana"></div>
  ```

  - **Aplicar**

    ```js
    // utilizando .attr()
    $( "#myBanana" ).attr( "data-fail", "no banana" );

    // utilizando .data()
    $( "#myBanana" ).data( "fail", "no monkey" );
    ```
  - **Recolher**

    ```js
    // utilizando .attr() da "no banana"
    console.log( $( "#myBanana" ).attr( "data-fail" ) );

    // utilizando .data() dá "no monkey"
    console.log ( $( "#myBanana" ).data( "fail" ) );
    ```
- #### Aplicar valor a atributo existente

  Se o atributo já existir no elemento, ao recolher o mesmo com qualquer um dos métodos, recebo o valor existente.

  Após realizar uma alteração ao valor, dependendo do método utilizado, o valor aplicado só é corretamente recolhido se utilizar o mesmo método para o obter:

  ```html
  <div id="myMonkey" data-fail="banana"></div>
  ```

  - **Recolher**

    ```js
    // utilizando .attr() dá "banana"
    console.log( $( "#myMonkey" ).attr( "data-fail" ) );

    // utilizando .data() dá "banana"
    console.log ( $( "#myMonkey" ).data( "fail" ) );
    ```
  - **Alterar**

    ```js
    // utilizando .attr()
    $( "#myMonkey" ).attr( "data-fail", "No banana" );

    // utilizando .data()
    $( "#myMonkey" ).data( "fail", "More banana" );
    ```
  - **Voltar a recolher**

    ```js
    // utilizando .attr() dá "No banana"
    console.log( $( "#myMonkey" ).attr( "data-fail" ) );

    // utilizando .data() dá "More banana"
    console.log ( $( "#myMonkey" ).data( "fail" ) );
    ```

  Ao início ambos os métodos foram recolher o mesmo valor que já se encontrava presente no atributo `data`, mas após alterar esse valor, tenho que usar o mesmo método para aplicar e recolher valores ou os resultados divergem.

Torna-se óbvio que o facto do atributo se chamar `data-*`, não está diretamente relacionado com o método `.data()` mas sim com o método `.attr()`.

Além disso ambos os métodos parecem interagir com o atributo `data` até um certo ponto, mas cada um tem a sua forma de guardar novos valores atribuídos.

Ao analisar o que acontece-se em termos de manipulação do DOM, também são visíveis diferenças substâncias causadas pelo uso de cada um dos métodos:

[image: Captura de Tela]

O método `.attr()` efectivamente está a atualizar o valor do atributo `data` enquanto que o método `.data()` não mexe no valor do atributo, estando sim a anexar ao elemento um identificador com o respetivo valor.

## Pergunta

Qual a diferença entre o método `.attr()` e o método `.data()` em termos de utilização, finalidade e impacto no elemento, para fazer uso da atribuição de dados arbitrários que o HTML5 disponibiliza ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Os dois métodos são completamente diferentes

#### `.data()`

O `.data()` foi criado com a finalidade de se associar dados arbitrários a um elemento do DOM. Na verdade, esse método é uma interface para o [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), que faz parte do core do jQuery.

Os dados são armazenados em um objeto interno, e lá são associados ao elemento do DOM em questão. Os dados não ficam pendurados diretamente no objeto que representa o elemento. Isto fica bem claro se você olhar o [código-fonte](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js). Com a consolidação dos atributos `data-` no HTML5*, o `.data()` passou a ler o atributo do HTML caso não encontre uma chave equivalente.

Portanto, não considere o `.data` como um método para se lidar com atributos `data-`. Ele é mais do que isso. Além do mais, ele possui duas diferenças fundamentais (uma delas você apontou na pergunta):

1. Ao escrever dados com `.data()`, o atributo `data-` correspondente não é afetado
2. Se o nome do seu atributo contém underscores ou hífens, o `.data()` aplica `camelCase` no nome antes de usá-lo como chave interna.

#### `.attr()`

O `.attr()` é dedicado a trabalhar com atributos. Ele sempre vai ler de um atributo e escrever em um atributo, ou seja, modifica o DOM, ao contrário do `.data()`. Pessoalmente, é meu método preferido para lidar com atributos `data-`, especialmente por não alterar os nomes com camelização como faz o `.data()`.

---

<sup>* Não tenho tanta certeza sobre a cronologia aqui</sup>

Answer (score 7):

A principal razão para esse comportamento foi explicada na respsta do @bfavaretto (diferença entre os dados arbitrários mantidos pelo jQuery e os atributos `data-*`), mas ainda que o jQuery não fizesse nada de especial com o `data`, ele ainda não se comportaria da forma esperada.

Citando [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/520779) no SOEN:

> Um elemento DOM é um objeto, uma coisa na memória. Como a maioria dos objetos na POO, ele possui **propriedades**. Ele também, separadamente, tem um mapeamento dos atributos definidos no elemento (em geral vindos do *markup* que o browser leu para criar o elemento). Algumas das **propriedades** do elemento ganham seu valor **inicial** a partir dos **atributos** com o mesmo nome ou nome similar (`value` ganha seu valor inicial do atributo "value"; `href` ganha seu valor inicial do atributo "href", mas não é exatamente o mesmo valor; `className` do atributo "class"). Outras propriedades ganham seus valores iniciais de outras maneiras: Por exemplo, a propriedade `parentNode` ganha seu valor baseado em qual é seu elemento pai; um elemento sempre tem uma propriedade `style`, independentemente de se ele tem um atributo "style" ou não.

Versões anteriores do jQuery misturavam atributos com propriedades, resultando em comportamentos estranhos. A partir da versão `1.6` separou-se o método [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) do [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (não sem uns [acidentes no percurso](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/)...), de modo que **conceitualmente** não faz muito sentido se continuar usando `attr` - já que na grande maioria dos casos o que se quer é `prop`. Até a versão `1.9` ainda mantinha-se esses dois métodos sincronizados, por questões de compatibilidade, mas a partir daí eles foram separados de vez.

Considere o seguinte markup:

```html
<input value="foo">
```

E o seguinte JavaScript:

```javascript
$("input").prop("value", "propriedade");
$("input").attr("value", "atributo");
```

Qual será o valor da caixa de texto ao final da execução? Se você executar isso no jQuery 1.8, será `"atributo"` (pois ele foi atribuído por último, e tanto faz usar `attr` ou `prop`). Se você usar o 1.9, será `"propriedade"` (pois o `attr` só modificou o markup, o objeto DOM continuou inalterado). [Exemplo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/K3sLR/3/), [Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/K3sLR/4/).

Desse modo, não espere que o `attr` se mantenha atualizado conforme os elementos no DOM mudam, use-o apenas se quiser obter o **estado inicial** dos mesmos (i.e. o que veio escrito no markup).

---

**Atualização:** o comportamento do `.data` hoje é bem diferente do que eu me lembrava. Fiz uns [testes adicionais](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/K3sLR/5/), e agora posso entender como ele funciona:

- Se não existe um valor atribuído programaticamente através do método `.data(chave, valor)`, então ele usa o valor do atributo `data-chave`.

  - Isso vale tanto para a ausência de atribuição quanto para a **remoção** desse valor.
- Se existe, ele usa o valor atribuído - ignorando o atributo.
- Não há propriedade `data-chave`, `dataChave`, etc.

Exemplo:

```html
<div id="teste" data-foo="10">
```

```javascript
$("#teste").data("foo"); // 10

$("#teste").data("foo", 20);
$("#teste").data("foo"); // 20

$("#teste").attr("data-foo", 30);
$("#teste").data("foo"); // ainda 20

$("#teste").removeData("foo");
$("#teste").data("foo"); // 30
```

Comment: Interessante, em suma o método `.attr()` dá-nos o valor presente na markup, o `.data()` dá-nos o valor da markup quando não existe nenhuma atribuição após o carregamento da página, ou o valor atual se já alterado! O `.prop()` a partir da versão 1.9 do jQuery assume o mesmo comportamento do método `.data()`, entendi bem?

Comment: @Zuul na verdade estou confuso, depois que postei a resposta fiz mais uns testes e reparei que o `data` mudou completamente o seu comportamento (conforme o bfavaretto falou, isso foi depois que o HTML5 consolidou os atributos `data-*`). Ainda não tenho muita certeza de como ele se comporta. Mas de qualquer forma, a ideia que quis passar nessa resposta foi que o `attr` se refere ao texto do markup, e o `prop` se refere a uma propriedade (campo, membro) do objeto no DOM.

Comment: @Zuul (esclarecendo: o comportamento era um da última vez que chequei - por volta da versão `1.6` -  e hoje é outro; não tinha me atentado para esse fato quando formulei a resposta)

Comment: Excelente explicação do `attr`. Detalhe: se você definir/alterar o valor de um atributo com `attr`, e depois tentar lê-lo novamente com `attr`, o valor lido será o novo. Portanto, o `attr` não lê somente o valor inicial, ele simplesmente combina `getAttribute` e `setAttribute`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Correto! Mas o importante é que a propriedade não é afetada por essa alteração. Ex.: digite "teste" na caixa de texto; use o código `$("input").attr("value", "foobar")`; depois desse código, se você olhar pra caixa de texto verá que seu valor ainda é "teste". Se você usar um `form submit` sem JavaScript, o valor passado ainda será "teste". Ou seja, mesmo havendo correspondência entre o `attr` do jQuery e os `getAttribute` e `setAttribute` do DOM, não há correspondência entre os mesmos e a propriedade em si.

Comment: Interessante, parece ser um caso especial de forms. Testei com `rel` e `href` (que acredito serem propriedades), e alterar o atributo também alterou a propriedade (http://jsfiddle.net/LD3GX/).